# Codeigniter extended core exception class function issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have extend codeigniter native library (exceptions) and define a new function.

Here is code

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }

    public function custom_errors($id, $message) {
        try {
//some code here
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }

}
```

I put this above class in `application/core/My_Exceptions.php` for autoload as mention in documentation. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

The problem is, i can't access function `custom_errors($id, $message)` in controller while `show_error()` is available in the same controller

I try like this

```
$this->my_exceptions->custom_errors($id, $message)
```

And

```
$this->exceptions->custom_errors($id, $message)
```

But get this error "Call to a member function custom_errors() on a non-object"

If codeigniter autoload it than it should be available here.

Please help me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: why dont you put in libraries inside application folder, no need to autoload it then, this will merge into base class, just load base class..

Comment: I am overriding base class functions.So have to put in application/core/ for autoload.